# Firebase-Invite Dynamic Link Unity iOS - Dynamic link opens the App, but can't retrieve the content of the link

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-invites

I've finally succeeded on implementing the dynamic link (manually created and the shortened by the Rest API), that works fine and opens the game when clicked.

The thing is, once opened, I can't retrieve anything from it. I've copied the example code [from the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/unity), added some logs, and nothing.

Here is my code,

```
// When the app starts, check to make sure that we have
// the required dependencies to use Firebase, and if not,
// add them if possible.
void Start()
{
    dependencyStatus = Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckDependencies();
    if (dependencyStatus != Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
    {
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.FixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            dependencyStatus = Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckDependencies();
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                InitializeFirebase();
            } else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
            }
        });
    } else {
        InitializeFirebase();
    }
}

// Set the listeners for the various Invite received events.
void InitializeFirebase()
{
    Firebase.Invites.FirebaseInvites.InviteReceived += OnInviteReceived;
    Firebase.Invites.FirebaseInvites.InviteNotReceived += OnInviteNotReceived;
    Firebase.Invites.FirebaseInvites.ErrorReceived += OnErrorReceived;
    Debug.Log("Invites initialized");
}

void OnInviteReceived(object sender, Firebase.Invites.InviteReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Log ("OnInviteRecieved");
    if (e.InvitationId != "")
    {
        Debug.Log("Invite received: Invitation ID: " + e.InvitationId);
        Firebase.Invites.FirebaseInvites.ConvertInvitationAsync(e.InvitationId).ContinueWith(HandleConversionResult);
    }
    if (e.DeepLink.ToString () != "")
    {
        Debug.Log ("Invite received: Deep Link: " + e.DeepLink);
        PrepareLevel (e.DeepLink.ToString ());
    }
}

void OnInviteNotReceived(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Log ("OnInviteNotReceived");
    Debug.Log("No Invite or Deep Link received on start up");
}

void OnErrorReceived(object sender, Firebase.Invites.InviteErrorReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Log ("OnErrorReceived");
    Debug.LogError("Error occurred received the invite: " + e.ErrorMessage);
}

void HandleConversionResult(Task convertTask)
{
    Debug.Log ("HandleConversionResult");
    if (convertTask.IsCanceled) {
        Debug.Log("Conversion canceled.");
    } else if (convertTask.IsFaulted) {
        Debug.Log("Conversion encountered an error:");
        Debug.Log(convertTask.Exception.ToString());
    } else if (convertTask.IsCompleted) {
        Debug.Log("Conversion completed successfully!");
    }
}
```

And here is the logs I get from the device (iPhone6S).

[image: execution_logs]

Also, "Invites initialized" has been prompted, and the object still exist when the app is opened from the dynamic link (it's never destroyed).

Oh, and I oppened the link via facebook messenger app.

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Having the same problem. I followed the iOS docs and compared with Unity's app delegate and found that the entry point is missing:

- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler

If I add this, I get the incoming URL (in Obj-C). I can then forward it to Unity, but I hardly think it's supposed to be that way - should the SDK not handle this automatically?

Comment: Its good to hear that I'm not the only one with this issue. I already contacted with the Firebase support team, they will hopefully provide the answer if something is missing or a fix in the upcoming release.
Best!